# Cannot change the mysql connection limit

Tags: mysql, connection, limit

I am on linux box running only mysql with 8 cores and 16GB ram.  All connections come from web server on another machine in the same network running php with codeigniter.

I cannot get more than 150 connections on mysql.

My my.cnf is:

```
[mysqld]
user=mysql
port            = 3306
socket          = /tmp/mysql.sock
datadir = /usr/local/mysql/var/
skip-external-locking
max_connections=500
max_user_connections=500
open-files-limit = 500
key_buffer_size = 2048M
max_allowed_packet = 32M
table_open_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
thread_cache_size = 250
table_definition_cache = 1024

query_cache_size = 32M
query_cache_limit = 32M
table_cache=1024
max_heap_table_size=1024M
key_buffer=2048M
wait_timeout=60
thread_concurrency = 16
long_query_time = 1
tmp_table_size=256M
```

show status returns that max_connections and max_user_connections to be 500.

Since mysql is saying that connection limit is 500, I thought there are other setting in PHP, apache or codeigniter that is limiting the requests to mysql, but I cannot find any.  I've searched google for few days trying to find answers without any luck.

Are there limits set on any of the above mentioned software?  I will post configs if necessary.

Thank you.

Comment: I thought that i was getting limited to 150 clients because I was using load testing software called Siege.  But same thing happens when I use ab with 200 concurrent connections.  I only get 150 mysql connections.  But the weird thing is, other clients using browsers can establish mysql connections beyond the 150.  So my question for this post might be "**How can I test web application load of more than 150 concurrent connections using load testing software, such as ab?**"

Answer (score 0):

Check the Max number of Apache worker processes (ServerLimit and MaxClients) in httpd.conf.  Assuming a fixed number of connections per worker, you might be maxing out your number of workers, so nothing is requesting new MySQL connections.

Comment: Here is my worker.c config from httpd.conf
`    <IfModule worker.c>
    ServerLimit 60
    StartServers 2
    MaxClients 1500
    MinSpareThreads 25
    MaxSpareThreads 75
    ThreadsPerChild 25
    MaxRequestsPerChild 1000
    </IfModule>`

sorry, don't know how to format in reply.  I don't think my setting here is limiting mysql connections to 150.

Comment: @user1839694 if you can only have 60 worker processes, figure how many connections you could possibly have based on the number you creating in your scripts.  If it's 2 or 3 connections being created, you're right around 150 max SQL connections.  Try creating a single php page  that loops through and creates connections to the DB 200 times without closing any... sleep for 500 ms between each.  When you get to 2 minutes, check your db connections Does the number of mysql connection go past 150?

Comment: My ThreadsPerChild is 25.  60 workers X 25 = 1500, which is the MaxClients.  I'll try creating the suggested script.

Comment: @user1839694 Ah, your using the MPM worker not, prefork.  My bad.

Comment: I don't know how to create multiple connections to the same mysql on a single script, so I created one that keeps a connection open and hit it with siege (web application load testing software) with 200 simultaneous connections.  I only end up with 150 connections.  Well, 153 to be exact.  1 for the prompt, 2 more from a perisitant connection from other scripts.  Maybe I'm only thinking that I'm getting 150 connections because I'm using siege to load test my application, and it has limitations since it's 1 client hitting apache with multiple connections.

Comment: Thank you for making me think in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just found this on Google, but your config is foobar

```
max_connections=500
open-files-limit = 500
table_open_cache = 512
table_definition_cache = 1024
```

open-files-limit: 500  #; not good!

table_open_cache:  512... * 2+ open-files per table = 1024 open-files used minimum

max_connections: 500  each open connection starts a new file handle to buffer.

Your mysql will open some 130 tables just to start (core tables) which leaves you with a mere 240 file handles to share between data queries and connections. For each connection with a table query, 3+ file handles are consumed (connection, data table, index file(s)). That maxes your open-files long before you get 150 connections.  open-files-limit needs to start >2048 for that kind of DB usage.

more help:

```
show global status like '%open%';
show global status like '%onnect%';
```

see for yourself how many files/connections are actually in use.  some operating systems (Windows XP) hard limit files/network connections.  try googling "mysql 'YOUR-OS' 150 connections" and see if that is the limiting factor.

Comment: The next hurdle that must be cleared, is when you set open-files-limit=2048 and check open files, only to find you are still limited to 150 because mysql is ignoring the setting